# Yii Get data from another model using Relation

Tags: php, search, yii, relation

I am trying to filter a table in my view using the search function in my model.
I have two models which i need to get data from model `Evaluation` to another model `EvaluationDetails`.

i have this in my `EvaluationDetails` model

```
public function relations() {
        return array(
            'eval' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Evaluation', 'eval_id'),
        );
    }
```

i also have this in my search function

```
public function search($employee = '', $search_date_start = '', $search_date_end = '', $search = '') {

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->with = array('eval' => array('together' => true));
        $criteria->compare('employee_id', $this->employee_id);
        $criteria->compare('remarks', $this->remarks, true);
        $criteria->compare('eval_id', $this->eval_id);
        $criteria->compare('eval.evaluatee', $this->evaluatee_search);            

        $criteria->addSearchCondition('eval.evaluatee', $search);

        if ($employee != '')
            $criteria->compare('employee_id', $employee->company_id);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
        ));
    }
```

I am trying to filter a table where in the user will search for a name, pass the value in `$search` which is then used in the search function in my `EvaluationDetails` model
With this, i am getting an error.

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'employee_id' in where
>   clause is ambiguous. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT
>   COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) FROM `trx_evaluation_details` `t` LEFT OUTER
>   JOIN `trx_evaluation` `eval` ON (`t`.`eval_id`=`eval`.`id`) WHERE
>   ((eval.evaluatee LIKE :ycp0) AND (employee_id=:ycp1))

what seems to be the problem with my code. please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing from the error message, it looks like both EvaluationDetails and Evaluation have a field call "employee_id" (i am not sure)

But if so, you need to replace the

```
 $criteria->compare('employee_id', $employee->company_id);
```

with

```
 $criteria->compare('t.employee_id', $employee->company_id);
```

To explicitly tell yii the field is from EvaluationDetails  table.

BTW, u are using $employee->company_id (should be $employee->employee_id ?)

Comment: wow. i mean thanks for your response. it really saved my day. i've been searching for answers since yesterday..